# The most efficient way to compare object's property in two arrays

Tags: arrays, angular, object, for-loop

I need to check in Angular2 if one object's property in one array is the same in another array and return value. Is there any more efficient way to do it or maybe something similar to `.contains` in Swift?

```
doSomething(){
    for (let element1 of array1) {
        for (let element2 of array2) {
            if (element1.id == element2.id) {
                return Observable.fromPromise(element2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have to subscribe to this value because I am loading value from the database (in fromPromise):

```
this.doSomething().subscribe(id => {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with arrays it is usually more readable to use higher order methods;
in your case you could [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the outer array using the return of [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) through the inner array, and then [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it :

```
array2.filter( x =>
  array1.some( z => z.id == x.id )
).map(x => Observable.fromPromise(x) )
```

Comment: @maionam that makes sense but when I want to return this value and I'm subscribing to this function in different place `this.doSomething().subscribe` I got `Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'Observable<{}>[];`

Comment: the example I gave you is general practice when dealing with arrays, if you have a specific case in which this doesn't work you should try to make a fiddle; if you do let me know and I'll give it a look

Comment: I've updated a question a little bit, I need to return Observable to subscribe to it.

Comment: with map you're returning an array, I think you're looking for the elements inside, try `this.doSomething()[0].subscribe`

Comment: if you just want one element you can also use array.find

Answer (score 0):

=== for comparing values of id

```
   for (const element1 of array1) {
      for (const element2 of array2) {
        if (element1.id === element2.id) {
          return Observable.fromPromise(element2);
        }
      }
    }
```

if you whant to know if the property call id exist in both

```
for (const element1 of array1) {
 Object.keys(element1).forEach(key => {
      if(key === 'id') {
          for (const element2 of array2) {
            if (element2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              return Observable.fromPromise(element2);
            }
          }
        }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of `array1` and `array2`:
`array1.filter((item) => array2.includes(item));`

Comment: This is clever code for sure, but it doesn't answer the question. In the OP the arrays contain objects and the author needs to compare them by `id` property. So the filtering won't work as expected because `array2.includes(item)` will always return false for distinct objects, even if they have the same `id`

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example

```
array1 = [1,2,4,5,6]
array2 = [3,4,2,6]
array1.filter(a1=> array2.includes(a1)) //To print matching results
array1.filter(a1=> array2.includes(a1)).length == array1.length ? true:false //to validate similarity
```

Comment: This won't help the OP. The arrays in the question contain objects, and the OP needs to find which object in array2 have an object in array1 with the same `id` property, then emit an Observable of the matching object in array2